# JAXB doesn't unmarshall after updating java from 1.8.0_77 to 1.8.0_121

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Yesterday I updated java like posted in the title, now JAXB doesn't parse xml anymore. All objects are simply null, nothing seems to be set.

Given this POJO - ListMatchingProductsResponse

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ListMatchingProductsResponse", propOrder = {
        "listMatchingProductsResult",
        "responseMetadata"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListMatchingProductsResponse")
public class ListMatchingProductsResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "ListMatchingProductsResult")
    private ListMatchingProductsResult listMatchingProductsResult;
    @XmlElement(name = "ResponseMetadata")
    private ResponseMetadata responseMetadata;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns")
    private String xmlns;

    public String getXmlns() {
        return xmlns;
    }

    public void setXmlns(String xmlns) {
        this.xmlns = xmlns;
    }


    /**
     * Get the value of ListMatchingProductsResult.
     *
     * @return The value of ListMatchingProductsResult.
     */
    public ListMatchingProductsResult getListMatchingProductsResult() {
        return listMatchingProductsResult;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of ListMatchingProductsResult.
     *
     * @param listMatchingProductsResult The new value to set.
     */
    public void setListMatchingProductsResult(ListMatchingProductsResult listMatchingProductsResult) {
        this.listMatchingProductsResult = listMatchingProductsResult;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of ResponseMetadata.
     *
     * @return The value of ResponseMetadata.
     */
    public ResponseMetadata getResponseMetadata() {
        return responseMetadata;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of ResponseMetadata.
     *
     * @param responseMetadata The new value to set.
     */
    public void setResponseMetadata(ResponseMetadata responseMetadata) {
        this.responseMetadata = responseMetadata;
    }
}
```

And the ListMatchingProductsResult

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="ListMatchingProductsResult", propOrder={
    "products"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListMatchingProductsResult")
public class ListMatchingProductsResult {

    @XmlElement(name="Products")
    private ProductList products;

    /**
     * Get the value of Products.
     *
     * @return The value of Products.
     */
    public ProductList getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of Products.
     *
     * @param products
     *            The new value to set.
     */
    public void setProducts(ProductList products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if Products is set.
     *
     * @return true if Products is set.
     */
    public boolean isSetProducts() {
        return products != null;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("products", products)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

I use this for unmarshalling:

```
String s = getResult();
// s is the expected xml string
ListMatchingProductsResponse m = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(s), ListMatchingProductsResponse.class);
log.info(m); // ListMatchingProductsResponse@7164e54
log.info(m.getListMatchingProductsResult()); // null
```

I'm a bit lost as I don't see any kind of reason for this, nor did I find any changes regarding JAXB in the changelog.

What am I doing wrong here?

The following answers didn't solve my issue so far

[JAXB Configuration was broken by upgrading from JDK 1.7 to JDK 1.8 u05 for collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664516/jaxb-configuration-was-broken-by-upgrading-from-jdk-1-7-to-jdk-1-8-u05-for-colle)

[Unmarshalling jaxB doesn't work, objects null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771769/unmarshalling-jaxb-doesnt-work-objects-null)

[Unmarshall with JAXB doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635784/unmarshall-with-jaxb-doesnt-work)

UPDATE

I now have included the following dependency to my project

```
group: 'org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2', name: 'maven-jaxb2-plugin', version: '0.13.1'
```

and it works again. So new question - why is that? Is there something missing / a bug in the 121 java release?

Comment: `maven-jaxb2-plugin` is a Maven plugin for code generation, you are not supposed to include it as compile or runtime dependencies.

Comment: @lexicore I tried several different jaxb dependencies, none worked - but including above one did. While I get that it doesn't make any sense, I'd like to know why including this makes it work again...

Comment: `maven-jaxb2-plugin` itself has dependencies to JAXB libraries. So basically you "inherit" dependencies from the Maven plugin (instead of having them on your own). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413431/which-artifacts-should-i-use-for-jaxb-ri-in-my-maven-project

Comment: Have similar problem with JAXB. First noticed it with jdk1.8.0_102. Haven't had a need before now to investigate and fix

Comment: I have a similar issue. I was upgrading from 1.8.0_91 to 1.8.0_121 (to get letsencrypt cert support), but _121 fails to parse my xml (all fields are null). I have tried generating with both JDK, and parsing with both JDKs, and parsing always fails with _121. This sounds like a parsing issue with _121, since _91 can parse XML even when classes are generated with _121.

Answer (score 4):

I have edited this, as it turns out that the change in the JRE was not technically a bug, but 1.8u91 and previous versions were more lenient, and allowed invalid namespaced XML, and 1.8u101+ breaks if xml is not correctly namespaced.

I have created an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/KlausGroenbaek/jaxbissue) to illustrate the difference. Try two run the two mains `NoSchema` and `WithSchema` using 1.8u91, and 1.8u101+ to see the difference in behaviour.

In my case the XML contained no default namespace, but the elements were not prefixed with the namespace they belonged to (`broker.xml`). This worked fine in 1.8u91, but failed in 1.8u101. Although upgrading broke our code, this is technically not Oracles fault, since the XML was incorrectly namespaced.

Comment: While I was trying to build a standalone example, I discovered the following: ` jaxb2-maven-plugin` creates both a `package-info.java` and an ObjectFactory.java.  If I remove the package-info (or its @XmlSchema annotation) then Jaxb also works on u101+. So maybe the older versions was more lenient, and the newer version is more strict.

Comment: Life-saver answer - thanks. My object unmarshalling started failing when we upgraded to JRE 1.8.101 and *no* exceptions were being printed to the log.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue of unmarshelling giving null values in jdk 101+ versions and solved by including `package-info.java` and annotation `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema`

Below is my code

`@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,namespace="http://example.com/api`")
package org.example;

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java8 newer version is more strict, I had same issue and found, we have to specify namespace for each field as follow to validate 
It worked for me

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ListMatchingProductsResponse", propOrder = {
        "listMatchingProductsResult",
        "responseMetadata"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListMatchingProductsResponse", namespace="http://example.com/api)
public class ListMatchingProductsResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "ListMatchingProductsResult", namespace="http://example.com/api)
    private ListMatchingProductsResult listMatchingProductsResult;
    @XmlElement(name = "ResponseMetadata", namespace="http://example.com/api)
    private ResponseMetadata responseMetadata;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns", namespace="http://example.com/api)
    private String xmlns;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced [the same issue](https://github.com/tnaskali/bgg-api/issues/1) when unmarschalling basic, non-namespaced XML using classes generated from a schema with the `elementFormDefault` property set to `qualified`. Simply using the (default) `unqualified` value solved the problem for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="unqualified">
...
</xs:schema>
```